# Python ast and tokenizer

Tags: python, parsing, tokenize, abstract-syntax-tree

In python how would you use the `tokenize` module in conjunction with the `ast` module? Both use different node types how would you correlate the two together? Is there a way? Possibly the `parser` module?

Comment: The `parser` module is not really going to help here. What exactly are you trying to do? The `ast` module parsers into tokens then builds the parse tree for you; the `tokenize` module just creates the tokens, nothing more. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: First off I have to say that this is for work and it is not my choice to do this. Having said that I am using the ast module to parse python files and do transforms on certain code elements like convert `func_a(l)` -> `func_a(func_b(l))` but the resulting output once I pass the ast through the astor.codegen.py contains all the logical parenthesis associated with different statements, like `a + 'string' + concat` -> `((a+'string')+concat)` but my job does not want all these parenthesis. So I am trying to do a final pass with tokenize to remove the parans but I need ast to find the statements

Comment: That is just a simplistic tree-to-source implementation adding parenthesis around every `BinOp` node to not have to think about operator precedence. I am not sure why a tokenizer would be the best solution to fix that; are you saying you want to use the tokenizer to record how the original code used parenthesis around the same operators so you can re-create that?

Comment: I can use the BinOp node to tell the tokenizer what parenthesis to remove.

Comment: Did you found solution ?